# Select each record from table without repeating same record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How do I select each record without repeating the same record?

Example:

```
ID            item
------       -------
ABC          item 1
XXX          item 2
AXA          item 3
ABC          item 4
XXX          item 5
```

From the table above, I just want to select each record such as ABC, XXX and AXA without repeating it. How do I do so in MS SQL 2005?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use "DISTINCT" Keyword for getting distinct records 
you can use the following query,

"SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM "

Answer (score 2):

Use the `distinct` key word:

```
Select distinct id from TABLE;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID from YourTable
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select Distinct ID from tablename
```

Answer (score 2):

The DISTINCT keyword can be used to return only distinct (different) values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT you_column_name FROM your_table_name
```

Answer (score 2):

The **DISTINCT** keyword can be used to return only distinct (different) values.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

So you can use this query:

> SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Table_name

Answer (score 1):

select distinct id from tablename